# Keep logo position fixed on responsive navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having problems styling a responsive navbar. 
The expected behaviour is that all nav links are displayed on larger screens but are collapsed into a hidden mobile menu on smaller screen sizes.

In the following snippet on smaller screens, when the logo is clicked, the logo moves down to the middle of the dropdown.

How do I keep it(the logo) fixed to the top of the navbar and properly align the menu items?

```js
document.querySelector('.topbar-brand').addEventListener('click', () => document.querySelector('.topbar-nav').classList.toggle('responsive'));
document.addEventListener('scroll', () => document.querySelector('.topbar-nav').classList.remove('responsive'));
```

```css
.topbar {
  background-color: rgb(40, 58, 156);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  top: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.topbar-brand {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-family: cursive, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topbar-brand img {
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
}

.topbar-brand:hover,
.topbar-brand:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-self: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 900;
  display: block;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.nav-link:focus {
  background-color: rgba(41, 71, 240, 0.993);
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topbar-nav li {
    display: none;
  }
  .topbar {
    align-content: space-around;
    justify-content: start;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topbar-brand {
    margin-right: 5 rem;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .topbar-nav.responsive {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 2rem;
  }
  .topbar-nav.responsive li {
    display: initial;
  }
  .topbar-nav.responsive li {
    border-bottom: 0.1rem solid black;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="topbar sticky">
  <a class="topbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="" alt="logo"></a>
  <ul class="topbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#explore">Top Picks</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="users/login.html">Login</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: For .topbar-brand you can include: align-self: flex-start. This will overwrite the self-align: center as defined for .topbar. You also need to fix the margin settings for .topbar-brand: 5 rem cannot contain a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `margin-bottom: auto;` to `.topbar-brand`. Since it's a flex element this will force its alignment to the top.

Here is a good article with some more info regarding flexbox and auto margins: [CSS-tricks: The peculiar magic of flexbox and auto margins](https://css-tricks.com/the-peculiar-magic-of-flexbox-and-auto-margins/)

```js
document.querySelector('.topbar-brand').addEventListener('click', () => document.querySelector('.topbar-nav').classList.toggle('responsive'));
document.addEventListener('scroll', () => document.querySelector('.topbar-nav').classList.remove('responsive'));
```

```css
.topbar {
  background-color: rgb(40, 58, 156);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  top: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.topbar-brand {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-family: cursive, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topbar-brand img {
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
}

.topbar-brand:hover,
.topbar-brand:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-self: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 900;
  display: block;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.nav-link:focus {
  background-color: rgba(41, 71, 240, 0.993);
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topbar-nav li {
    display: none;
  }
  .topbar {
    align-content: space-around;
    justify-content: start;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topbar-brand {
    margin-right: 5 rem;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: auto;
  }
  .topbar-nav.responsive {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 2rem;
  }
  .topbar-nav.responsive li {
    display: initial;
  }
  .topbar-nav.responsive li {
    border-bottom: 0.1rem solid black;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="topbar sticky">
  <a class="topbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="" alt="logo"></a>
  <ul class="topbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#explore">Top Picks</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="users/login.html">Login</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```